# Function won't completely initialize until used as a callback function in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-selectors, shopping-cart

I am doing a shopping cart using jQuery and local storage and I have come across an occurring problem.

I have created a function `renderCart()`, which I want to show every time the page reloads, but if I initialize it inside my document.ready function it won't execute the code, but if I create a button #show-cart and I pass it my `renderCart()` function then after i click on it I will see the rendered cart.

Do you know why my code won't initialize when reloading the page and how can I make it work?.

```js
'use strict'

const products = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Bamboo Tootbrush",
    "price": 9.99,
    "description": "This is a description of the item that you are about to buy. It is eco-friendly and buy buying this product you are helping the environment and the planet..",
    "url": "css/img/item1.jpg",
    "sale": true,
    "category": "bathroom"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bamboo Dental Floss",
    "price": 10.99,
    "description": "This is a description of the item that you are about to buy. It is eco-friendly and buy buying this product you are helping the environment and the planet.",
    "url": "css/img/item2.jpg",
    "sale": false,
    "category": "bathroom"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bamboo Swabs",
    "price": 8.99,
    "description": "This is a description of the item that you are about to buy. It is eco-friendly and buy buying this product you are helping the environment and the planet.",
    "url": "css/img/item3.jpg",
    "sale": true,
    "category": "bathroom"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Eco-friendly Straws",
    "price": 12.99,
    "description": "This is a description of the item that you are about to buy. It is eco-friendly and buy buying this product you are helping the environment and the planet.",
    "url": "css/img/item4.jpg",
    "sale": true,
    "category": "kitchen"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Set of 3 produce bags",
    "price": 11.99,
    "description": "This is a description of the item that you are about to buy. It is eco-friendly and buy buying this product you are helping the environment and the planet.",
    "url": "css/img/item5.jpg",
    "sale": false,
    "category": "kitchen"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "MESH produce bags",
    "price": 11.99,
    "description": "This is a description of the item that you are about to buy. It is eco-friendly and buy buying this product you are helping the environment and the planet.",
    "url": "css/img/item6.jpg",
    "sale": false,
    "category": "kitchen"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Straws",
    "price": 11.99,
    "description": "This is a description of the item that you are about to buy. It is eco-friendly and buy buying this product you are helping the environment and the planet.",
    "url": "css/img/item7.jpg",
    "sale": false,
    "category": "kitchen"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Tootbrush ECOholic",
    "price": 11.99,
    "description": "This is a description of the item that you are about to buy. It is eco-friendly and buy buying this product you are helping the environment and the planet.",
    "url": "css/img/item8.jpg",
    "sale": false,
    "category": "bathroom"
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {

  //Nacitanie navigacie a footeru na vsetkych strankach
  $('.menu').load('http://127.0.0.1:5500/ITvKurze-Projekt/menu.html');
  $('footer').load('http://127.0.0.1:5500/ITvKurze-Projekt/footer.html');

  showFavProduct();
  showProduct();
  filter();
  addToCart();

  renderCart(); //this wont render

  //this below will
  $('#show-cart').click(function showCart() {
    renderCart();
  });

  addCartInfoToCartList();
  cartCount();

  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    console.log(products[i]);
  }


  $('.clear-btn').click(function clearCartbutton() {
    clearCart();
  });

  function addToCart() {
    $('.add-btn').on("click", function(e) {

      let productID = e.target.attributes.productid.value
      let actualCart = localStorage.getItem('productsID');

      if (actualCart == null) {
        actualCart = [];
      } else {
        actualCart = JSON.parse(actualCart);
      }

      actualCart.push(productID);
      localStorage.setItem('productsID', JSON.stringify(actualCart));

      console.log(`Just added product to cart with ID: ${ productID }`);
      cartCount();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(actualCart));
      renderCart();
    });
  };

  function addCartInfoToCartList() {
    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      products[i].qty = undefined;
    }

    let actualCart = localStorage.getItem('productsID');

    if (actualCart === null) {
      actualCart = [];
    } else {
      actualCart = JSON.parse(actualCart);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < actualCart.length; i++) {
      let productPosition = actualCart[i];

      if (products[productPosition].qty === undefined) {
        products[productPosition].qty = 1;
      } else {
        products[productPosition].qty++;
      }
    }
  }

  function cartCount() {
    let cartLength;
    if (!localStorage.getItem('productsID')) {
      cartLength = [];
      console.log('Your cart is empty');
      $('.cart').text(`(0)`);
      // !!!!! neviem preco mi nefunguje pri prvom inicializovani riadok vyssie !!!!
    } else {
      cartLength = localStorage.getItem('productsID');
      let cartCount = JSON.parse(cartLength).length;
      console.log(`Number of products in cart: ${ cartCount }.`);
      $('.cart').text(`(${ cartCount })`);
    }
  };

  function clearCart() {
    localStorage.clear();

    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      products[i].qty = undefined;
    }
    $('.cart-container').empty();
    console.log('Your cart is empty');
  };
  //ZOBRAZENIE PRODUKTOV V CART ELEMENTE
  function renderCart() {
    for (let i of products) {
      if (i.qty !== undefined) {
        let productDiv = `<div class="fav-wrap ${i.category}">`;
        productDiv += `<img class="fav" src="${i.url}">`;
        productDiv += `<div class="name">${ i.name }</div>`;
        productDiv += `<div>Price: ${ i.price } EUR</div>`
        productDiv += `<div class="add-btn" productid="${ i.id }">ADD TO CART</div>`;
        productDiv += '</div>';

        $('.cart-container').append(productDiv);
      };
    };
  };

  //Zobrazenie akciovych produktov na index.html v sekcii Our Favourites
  function showFavProduct() {
    for (let i of products) {
      if (i.sale === true) {
        let productDiv = `<div class="fav-wrap ${i.category}">`;
        productDiv += `<img class="fav" src="${i.url}">`;
        productDiv += `<div class="name">${ i.name }</div>`;
        productDiv += `<div>Price: ${ i.price } EUR</div>`
        productDiv += `<div class="add-btn" productid="${ i.id }">ADD TO CART</div>`;
        productDiv += '</div>';

        $('#fav-products').append(productDiv);
      }
    }
  }

  //Zobrazenie vsetkych produktov na SHOP.html
  function showProduct() {

    for (let i of products) {

      let productDiv = `<div class="fav-wrap ${i.category}">`;
      productDiv += `<img class="fav" src="${i.url}">`;
      productDiv += `<div class="name">${ i.name }</div>`;
      productDiv += `<div>Price: ${ i.price } EUR</div>`
      productDiv += `<div class="add-btn" productid="${ i.id }">ADD TO CART</div>`;
      productDiv += '</div>';

      $('#all-products').append(productDiv);
    }
  }

  //Vyber kategorie v SHOPE
  function filter() {
    $('#all').click(function() {
      $(".kitchen, .bathroom").show();
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      $("#cat-kitchen, #cat-bath").removeClass("selected");
    });

    $('#cat-kitchen').click(function() {
      $(".bathroom").hide();
      $(".kitchen").show();
      $("#all, #cat-bath").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    });

    $('#cat-bath').click(function() {
      $(".kitchen").hide();
      $(".bathroom").show();
      $("#all, #cat-kitchen").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected")
    });
  }
});
```

I expect that I will see the actual cart that I have stored in my local storage right after reloading the page, so I do not have to click the show cart button every time.

Comment: Does `$('.cart-container')` exist when page load, or you're adding it in ajax in different place? From where `products` variable came from? Is it returned from ajax call?

Comment: Yes the `.cart-container` exists in my html.file and I have written my variable `products` at the top inside my `script.js` file for now. @jcubic

Comment: Can you put your whole code then (inside the question)?

Comment: What if you `console.log(products)` ? Are you sure of its value? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Just did edited the whole code @jcubic

Comment: As an aside, `$('#show-cart').click(renderCart)` works too and is shorter. And backticks strings do support multiline, you don't have to add `productDiv +=` each line.

Comment: @JeremyThille The thing is that the function renderCart works well and I have no errors. But I want it to work and initialize it right after loading the page, so I do not have to click on a button to show it.

Comment: In your original array `qty` is not defined so the render will not work, you first need to add something to cart. You need to initalize the products from LocalStorage if they have `qty`.

Comment: Is the extra ' on the end of line 1 intentional?

Comment: @jcubic I know and I have added them to my cart in my `LocalStorage` and if I reload the page the render will not work, unless I click on the button I created to show it.

Again, the problem is that my `renderCart()`wont itinitialize after the reloading of the page, but it works when I pass it to my button.

Comment: @VirxEC sorry I forgot to include in my code one character from my code. corrected it.

Comment: The problem is that you don't do anything to products before you call renderCart so the loop do nothing, you need to get the data from LS first. You call addCartInfoToCartList that set qty but after you call renderCart. You need to change the order of the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code *does* run and your function *does* execute.

But it contains only a loop with `if (i.qty !== undefined)`.

And indeed, none of your objects contains `qty` at start, so the loop doesn't do anything. It does what it's supposed to do.

```
// No "qty" anywhere.
{ 
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bamboo Dental Floss",
      "price": 10.99,
      "description": "This is a description of the item that you are about to buy. It is eco-friendly and buy buying this product you are helping the environment and the planet.",
      "url": "css/img/item2.jpg",
      "sale": false,
      "category": "bathroom"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me understand it better and I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I now understand it.

My `addCartInfoToCartList();` which updates my products from LocalStorage was initialized (where it updates qty as well) after my renderCart(). I have changed the order.

Now it works.